# The partial sum and partial product of $\zeta$function

Tags: riemann-zeta, euler-product

Taking the partial sum of the $\zeta $ function:

$$\zeta^H(s,k)=\sum_{n=0}^k \frac{1}{n^s}$$

and the partial product f the $\zeta $ function:

$$\zeta^P(s,j)=\prod_{i=0}^j \frac{1}{1-p_i^{-s}}$$

I have two questions:

(1) For $p$ being prime and $n,k,i\in\Bbb N$; do there exist closed functions for $\zeta^H(s,k)$ and $\zeta^P(s,j)$ to which the partial sum respectively the partial product converge?

(2) Does anybody know from a proof that would confirm that for a given $s$, if and if only $j,k\to\infty$ then:
$$\zeta^H(s,k)-\zeta^P(s,j)\to0$$

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: If the real part of $s$ is greater than 1, then both finite product and finite sum converge absolutely to $\zeta(s)$.

Comment: sure, this is trivial. But my questions were about what happens before?

Answer (score 0):

For $s=1$ and positive nonzero integer $k$ you have the harmonic numbers. Their numerators  are in the OEIS as sequence **A001008** and their denominators as **A002805**.

That being said, there are other formulas that express your function $\zeta^H$. For instance, [this paper by Borwein, Fee,  Ferguson and Van Der Waall](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/personal/pborwein/PAPERS/P172.pdf) proposes the following (by denoting your function $\zeta^H (s,k)$ by $\zeta_N(s)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{N}n^{-s}$):

$$
\zeta(s) = \zeta_{N-1}(s) +N^{-s} + \frac{N^{1-s}}{a-1} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{B_{2n}}{(2n)!}\left( \prod_{j=0}^{2n-2} (s+j) \right) N^{1-s-2n} + R,
$$

where the $B_n$ are the Bernouilli numbers.