# Summation of roots

Tags: summation, roots

In this post, [Calculate summation of square roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/938225/calculate-summation-of-square-roots) we are shown how to sum square roots. My question is, can we get similarly simple expressions if instead of square roots we choose some other exponent. More specifically, is there a simple approximating expression for

$\sum_{i=1}^N i^{2/3}$

Comment: Using Riemann sums gives you integral bounds. For an approximation, use $\int_1^N x^{2/3} dx = (3/5)(N^{5/3}-1)$

Comment: @lhf Can you post your suggestion as an answer, perhaps with an error estimate?

Answer (score 3):

Well writing $\;\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^N k^a=H_N^{\left(-a\right)}\;$ is just a rewriting using [generalized harmonic numbers](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.5430.pdf).
Writing this as a [partial zeta sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397506) or [truncated zeta function $\zeta_N(-a)$](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/experimental-mathematics/volume-16/issue-1/Zeros-of-Partial-Summs-of-the-Riemann-Zeta-Function/em/1175789799.pdf) is exactly the same thing!
You get too $\;\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^N k^a =\zeta(-a) - \zeta(-a, N+1)\;$ using the [Hurwitz zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function).

For $a$ integer you get [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) and for real or even complex values $\,a\neq -1\,$ excellent approximations are provided by the [Euler-Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula#Examples) (with $s=-a$) :
$$\sum_{k=1}^N k^a \sim\zeta(-a)+\frac {N^{a+1}}{a+1}+\frac {N^a}2-\sum_{i\ge 1}\frac{B_{2i}}{(2i)!}\frac{(s+2i-2)!\;N^{a-2i+1}}{(s-1)!}$$
(note that this is an asymptotic expansion and that the sum at the right has to remain finite with $B_j$ a [Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number))

Answer (score 2):

For (increasing) concave functions $f$ with $f(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty,$ for example $f(x) = x^{2/3},$ integrating i.e. finding the area under the curve between $1$ and $a,$ $\displaystyle\int_1^a f(x)\ dx,$ can give you a *relatively* good approximation to the sum $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{a} f(n)$, but not a good *absolute* difference. If you want to be more precise then you have to do a bit more work.

For (increasing) concave functions $f$ with $f(x)\to c\in\mathbb{R}$ as $x\to\infty,$ for example $f(x) = 1-1/x,$ integrating between $1$ and $a,$ $\displaystyle\int_1^a f(x)\ dx,$ not only gives you a good *relative* approximation but in fact can give you a good *absolute* approximation to $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{a} f(n)$: in the case of $f(x)=1-1/x$ the area under the curve (i.e. the integral) differs from the sum $\sum_n 1/n$ by a maximum of some *constant* which is probably less than $2$.

Seeing these things is not so difficult once you've drawn diagrams to see what's going on.